# How to make eth0:0 permanent in 01-netcfg.yaml in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: networking, ethernet

Adding eth0:0 is easy with `sudo ifconfig eth0:0 10.5.1.251`
But how do I add it so it survives a reboot?

I have only been able find how to add it in /etc/network/interfaces but that does not work in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Show us what you added to `/etc/interfaces`, what you did to test, and be specific about the failure.

Comment: I didn't try adding anything to  /etc/network/interfaces because https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu says "The former network configuration file /etc/network/interfaces is not used anymore." So I assumed the replacement (01-netcfg.yaml) should be able to do the trick. I just can't figure out how.